# How to retrieve and display UIIMages stored in an array?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, core-graphics

I'm trying to cut an image into 9 pieces, store them in an array, then redistribute them randomly across the screen.

I've figured out how to create a new UIIMageView programmatically and set its background color so I can see where it is, but I can't get a cropped section of the user's selected image (`displayImageView.image`) to display in the `tiledView, UIImageView` after pressing the `randomize` button.

I tried storing all the tiles in the `tileStack` array, each piece being 1/3 the size of the `displayImageView.image`. Not sure if the hang up is in how I'm slicing and storing the images, or in how I'm calling the array element into the view.

(I'm just trying to get one piece/tile to display now; later I'm going to use a for loop to display all 9 pieces.)

```
//Beginning of function to cut photo into 9 tiles, then randomize them. 

//Cut selected image into 9 pieces and add each cropped image to tileStack array. 

@IBAction func randomize(sender: AnyObject) {

let tileSize = CGSizeMake(displayImageView.image!.size.width/3, displayImageView.image!.size.height/3)

    for (var rowI = 0; rowI < 3; rowI++)
    {
        for (var colI = 0; colI < 3; colI++)
        {
            let tileRect = CGRectMake(CGFloat(rowI) * tileSize.width, tileSize.height * CGFloat(colI), tileSize.width, tileSize.height)

            let tileImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(displayImageView.image!.CGImage, tileRect)

            if let selectedImage = displayImageView.image
            {
                let tileImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(selectedImage.CGImage, tileRect)
                tileStack.append(tileImage!)
            }

        }
    }

    //display tiles in order on screen

    var tiledView : UIImageView
    tiledView = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(50, 150, 100, 100))
    tiledView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    tiledView.center = CGPointMake(150, 150)
    tiledView.image = tileStack[3] as? UIImage
    self.view.addSubview(tiledView)

}
```

Comment: is it not possible to make the UIImageViews on a storyboard first instead of creating them at run time? then it will be easier to position / assign the images to the UIImageViews

Comment: CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(displayImageView.image!.CGImage, tileRect) returns a CGImage which is actually not a image but bitmap representation of image you should convert CGImage to UIImage using below code  var aNewUIImage = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @AjayBeniwal! That solved my problem! 
Yes @Fonix, but I'm wanting to use a for loop to create several UIImageViews. Thanks for the comment though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(displayImageView.image!.CGImage, tileRect) returns a CGImage which is actually not a image but bitmap representation of image you should convert CGImage to UIImage using below code var aNewUIImage = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef) – @Ajay Beniwal